# ReGex Python brackets and parenthesis

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, pattern-matching, brackets

I have several inputs of the form

```
intput1: 'some text1 \(blabla1\) some text2 \[blabla2\] some text3 \[blabla3\]'
intput2: '\(bla1\) some text'
intput3: '\[bla2\] some text and \[bla3\]'
```

and so on.

(the number and the order of (...), [...] are not fixed)

For each input i I would like a list output_i of the form

```
output_1=[some text1, \(blabla1\),some text2, \[blabla2\], some text3]
output_2=[\(bla1\),some text]
output_3=[\(bla2\),some text and, \[bla3\]]
```

I tried to use the following:

```
totreat = re.split(r'\\\((.*?)\\\)|\\\[(.*?)\\\]|\\\)(.*?)\\\(|\\\](.*?)\\\[|\\\)(.*?)\\\[|\\\](.*?)\\\(',src)
```

without any success

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given an input string `i`, you split the string by whitespace and then can use `itertools.groupby` to group the output based on whether or not each substring starts and ends with brackets:

```
from itertools import groupby
[' '.join(g) for _, g in groupby(i.split(), key=lambda s: s.startswith(('\(', '\[')) and s.endswith(('\)', '\]')))]
```

This returns, given your input strings from `intput1`, `intput2`, `intput3`, respectively:

```
['some text1', '\\(blabla1\\)', 'some text2', '\\[blabla2\\]', 'some text3', '\\[blabla3\\]']
['\\(bla1\\)', 'some text']
['\\[bla2\\]', 'some text and', '\\[bla3\\]']
```